# Adjusting column width in tabularx

Tags: tables

I have to following table (originally generated from R by the `tables` package and pruned for this question):

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{0.49\textwidth}{XXXXXXX}
\toprule
$A$ & $B$ & $C$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ $D$ } & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$E$} \\ 
\midrule
100 & 0.25 & 100  & \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{$0.21$} & \multicolumn{1}{@{ $\pm$ }l}{$0.06$} & \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{$0.05$} & \multicolumn{1}{@{ $\pm$ }l}{$0.04$}\\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

I would like the total width of the table fixed and the first three columns to take less space, leaving more for the multicolumns. I tried the solutions for related questions, but it didn't work out. Can anybody help please?

Comment: Then don't use `X` for those columns

Comment: You don't want X for the first three columns so they are set natural width, and the multicolumn are over-riding the X entry on the remaining columns, and all entries appear to be in math mode, are you sure you don't want an array rather than tabularx?

Comment: Thank you David, I already suspected the overriding to be happening. Actually I'm automatically generating my latex tables form within the R environment, such that the 'stuff within the table' like line 6 should be taken 'as is' and not manually modified. I'm not sure if tabularx is actually the best way to do what I wanna do.